# Дочерний блок шире родительского блока с ограниченной шириной. Как сделать?

Tags: html, css

Имеется колонка с текстом. На странице она одна и занимает примерно 70% от всей ширины страницы. Расположена по-центру.
[image: Страница]

Внутри текст и некоторые другие элементы, включая изображения.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы изображения занимали, скажем, 90% от ширины **всей** страницы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут все дело вот в чем.

1. Использовать `position: absolute` не получится, потому как часть текста не будет видна, ибо будет находиться **за** картинкой.
2. Просто указать ширину равную, скажем, 180% для изображения тоже нельзя, иначе результат будет примерно следующий.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Также стоит учесть, что изображения могут быть разные по ширине. Из этого следует, что нужно сделать следующее: более мелкие изображения, которые не дотягивают до ширины колонки, нужно растягивать так, чтобы они занимали 100% ширины род. элемента. А те, что шире нужно растягивать так, чтобы занимали не более 90% от ширины всей страницы. Грубо говоря все это дело должно выглядеть примерно так:

> ```
> img {
>     min-width: 100%; /* от ширины родителя */
>     max-width: 90%; /* от ширины всей страницы */
> }
> ```

Как подобное можно реализовать? Допускается обрамлять `img` в `div`'ы и другие теги.

Вспомнил об еще одном не подходящем способе: вариант обрамления всего содержимого кроме картинок в дополнительный тег и придание ему `margin` или `padding`. Этот вариант не подходит как минимум по двум причинам: задача заключается в том, чтобы разрешить картинке быть на всю (почти) ширину страницы, оставаясь при этом по-центру, а не сместить все кроме картинок, чтобы они казались растянутыми (1). И использование дополнительных тегов (что будет крайне неудобно делать каждый раз) (2).

Comment: @DimXenon ну например Chrome ругается на отрицательные значения паддингов и не учитывает их.

Comment: Пардон, margin. Padding нельзя <0.

Comment: `width: 110%;margin-left: -5%;`

Comment: @DimXenon Это решает проблему более широкого доч. блока, но не решает дилеммы с маленькими-большими изображениями (а в вопросе уточняется, что это должно быть решено)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Достаточно использовать [относительные единицы](https://webref.ru/css/value/size) измерения.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px; /* Для красоты */
}
img {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
  max-width: 90vw;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam optio quasi sapiente labore enim nisi sit, facere adipisci corrupti distinctio. Fuga eos in debitis, recusandae rerum minus nulla sint doloribus ducimus dolore non, repellendus, ullam quia.
    Molestiae enim ratione eaque?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nemo sit qui dolorem, minima quibusdam. Cumque aperiam sint odio culpa totam alias explicabo suscipit voluptates officiis adipisci temporibus, amet ipsum, vero voluptatibus consequatur
    rerum, aut ullam. Sequi iusto, similique. Quis eaque, veritatis sapiente ea amet, veniam neque voluptatem repellendus possimus laboriosam quasi nam aliquam ullam similique, expedita. Quo aliquam molestias ratione nemo pariatur sed velit, sint nulla
    tempore eveniet maiores nesciunt explicabo quas! Nesciunt, reprehenderit! Soluta voluptatibus perferendis quod nam.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://satyr.io/200x200/1" alt="Demo 1">
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur a saepe eveniet similique laudantium non aut delectus, facere libero ut vitae, enim tempore magnam eligendi adipisci cum minus. Eius doloremque molestias, dolores consequatur hic! Culpa
    eveniet, velit nam dolor dignissimos!</p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://satyr.io/750x300/2" alt="Demo 2">
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam optio quasi sapiente labore enim nisi sit, facere adipisci corrupti distinctio. Fuga eos in debitis, recusandae rerum minus nulla sint doloribus ducimus dolore non, repellendus, ullam quia.
    Molestiae enim ratione eaque?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nemo sit qui dolorem, minima quibusdam. Cumque aperiam sint odio culpa totam alias explicabo suscipit voluptates officiis adipisci temporibus, amet ipsum, vero voluptatibus consequatur
    rerum, aut ullam. Sequi iusto, similique. Quis eaque, veritatis sapiente ea amet, veniam neque voluptatem repellendus possimus laboriosam quasi nam aliquam ullam similique, expedita. Quo aliquam molestias ratione nemo pariatur sed velit, sint nulla
    tempore eveniet maiores nesciunt explicabo quas! Nesciunt, reprehenderit! Soluta voluptatibus perferendis quod nam.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://satyr.io/750x300/3" alt="Demo 3">
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam optio quasi sapiente labore enim nisi sit, facere adipisci corrupti distinctio. Fuga eos in debitis, recusandae rerum minus nulla sint doloribus ducimus dolore non, repellendus, ullam quia.
    Molestiae enim ratione eaque?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nemo sit qui dolorem, minima quibusdam. Cumque aperiam sint odio culpa totam alias explicabo suscipit voluptates officiis adipisci temporibus, amet ipsum, vero voluptatibus consequatur
    rerum, aut ullam. Sequi iusto, similique. Quis eaque, veritatis sapiente ea amet, veniam neque voluptatem repellendus possimus laboriosam quasi nam aliquam ullam similique, expedita. Quo aliquam molestias ratione nemo pariatur sed velit, sint nulla
    tempore eveniet maiores nesciunt explicabo quas! Nesciunt, reprehenderit! Soluta voluptatibus perferendis quod nam.</p>
</div>
```

Разверните пример на всю страницу. Так лучше видно, что картинки 90% шириной.

Comment: Каково будет поведение при маленьких картинках? Попробуйте изменить свой ответ так, чтобы хоть одна картинка была меньше ширины блока с текстом.

Comment: Если все будет хорошо, то решение ваше. Кстати, почему вы не использовали max-width: 90vw?

Comment: @smellyshovel, исправил, тоже об этом подумал. Потому что эти единицы высчитываются на основе ширины окна браузера. Вам нельзя полагаться на ширину родителя. Я скинул ссылку на статью в ответе по этим единицам.

Comment: Да, я знаю об этих единицах, просто как-то о них совсем не подумал.

Comment: И я, пожалуй, дополню: нужно еще добавить `min-width: 100%`, чтобы решение точно смогло считаться ответом. А так - спасибо, что навели на мысль, очень признателен :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, точно, готово!

Answer (score 3):

#### Вариант расчёта через проценты от ширины родительского блока

Родительский блок занимает `70%` окна и расположен по центру. Изображение занимает `90%` от ширины окна. То есть, оно будет выступать влево и вправо на `10%` от ширины окна. Это составляет `10% / 70% = 0,1428571429` от ширины родительского блока.

А ширина изображения составит `90% / 70% = 1,2857142857` от ширины родителя.

Значит, нужно задать изображению такие свойства:

```
margin: 0 -14.28571429%;
width: 128.57142857%;
```

Проверяем:

```css
.container {
  background: #9c6;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  width: 70%;
}
.container img {
  margin: 0 -14.28571429%;
  width: 128.57142857%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="//placehold.it/800x400/c69/fff/" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Плюс от меня за то, что считать не поленился

Comment: Слишком костыльно, нет.