# Как сделать фото img (размер 1920х600) на всю ширину экрана (за пределы контейнера)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Получилось расположить фото на всю ширину при текущих условиях

```css
.full-width {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0px 30px 33.3%;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Там есть фрагмент с фото

```html
<figure class='full-width'>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WFbyXCB/foto1-Giza.jpg">    
  </figure>
```

Его не получается сделать на всю ширину экрана из-за условия, как раз делящего эту самую ширину

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
      article {
        flex: 0 0 60%;
        max-width: 60%;
        order: 1;
      }

      aside {
        flex: 0 0 40%;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        order: 2;
      }
    }
```

Как это можно здесь исправить и возможно ли? в идеале, чтобы изображение растягивалось на всю ширину экрана, а все остальное оставалось на своих местах.
Так как фото непосредственно располагается в теле article (

Comment: Вынеси figure class='full-width' из article в отдельный блок и задай нужную ширину. В чём сложность?
article +
div>figure + 
article

Comment: просто вынести не получится или я не понимаю? мне нужно, чтобы фото обязательно было внутри article, текст+фото и т.д. последовательно и все это в общей конструкции article, где по h2 формируется содержание, а фото как дополнение к тексту идет, думал стилями возможно есть вариант как-то преобразовать фото

Comment: Посидел, потыкался, у тебя в какой-то момент страница превращается в двухколоночную. Из-за этого родительский элемент для картинки уменьшается и становится трудно ей задать ширину 100vw. По крайней мере, я не вижу способа. Но мне удалось найти очень похожий на твой вопрос, сейчас в ответ напишу, здесь не помещается.

Comment: я тут выше (в начале вопроса) скомпоновал и свое и ваш код как приведенный пример, вроде получилось и горизонтальной полосы прокрутки нет. Это нормальное решение получилось? можете глянуть по первой ссылке на codepen, я пересохранил новый вариант

Comment: ссылки нет, или вопрос уже не актуален?

Comment: Iurii, проверил, сейчас должна быть ссылка

Comment: На низким разрешении экрана появляется горизонтальная прокрутка, полностью протестировать не могу, у меня JQuery неустановлен. Два момента, почему макет именно такой, мне показался несовременным, либо очень специализированным. Второй момент, проект уже начинает быть немаленьким, почему не используешь какую-нибудь CSS методологию?

Comment: вот странно, в другом редакторе смотрю на маленьком разрешении экрана - нет полосы прокрутки, а здесь показывается... да в целом это больше эксперимент так сказать "для себя"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Дочерний блок шире родительского блока с ограниченной шириной. Как сделать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556734/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0px 40px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam optio quasi sapiente labore enim nisi sit, facere adipisci corrupti distinctio. Fuga eos in debitis, recusandae rerum minus nulla sint doloribus ducimus dolore non, repellendus, ullam quia.
    Molestiae enim ratione eaque?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nemo sit qui dolorem, minima quibusdam. Cumque aperiam sint odio culpa totam alias explicabo suscipit voluptates officiis adipisci temporibus, amet ipsum, vero voluptatibus consequatur
    rerum, aut ullam. Sequi iusto, similique. Quis eaque, veritatis sapiente ea amet, veniam neque voluptatem repellendus possimus laboriosam quasi nam aliquam ullam similique, expedita. Quo aliquam molestias ratione nemo pariatur sed velit, sint nulla
    tempore eveniet maiores nesciunt explicabo quas! Nesciunt, reprehenderit! Soluta voluptatibus perferendis quod nam.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/977/Mountains_Scenery_473520_2048x1152.jpg" alt="image1">
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur a saepe eveniet similique laudantium non aut delectus, facere libero ut vitae, enim tempore magnam eligendi adipisci cum minus. Eius doloremque molestias, dolores consequatur hic! Culpa
    eveniet, velit nam dolor dignissimos!</p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/977/Mountains_Scenery_473520_2048x1152.jpg" alt="image2">
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam optio quasi sapiente labore enim nisi sit, facere adipisci corrupti distinctio. Fuga eos in debitis, recusandae rerum minus nulla sint doloribus ducimus dolore non, repellendus, ullam quia.
    Molestiae enim ratione eaque? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nemo sit qui dolorem, minima quibusdam. Cumque aperiam sint odio culpa totam alias explicabo suscipit voluptates officiis adipisci temporibus, amet ipsum, vero voluptatibus consequatur
    rerum, aut ullam. Sequi iusto, similique. Quis eaque, veritatis sapiente ea amet, veniam neque voluptatem repellendus possimus laboriosam quasi nam aliquam ullam similique, expedita. Quo aliquam molestias ratione nemo pariatur sed velit, sint nulla
    tempore eveniet maiores nesciunt explicabo quas! Nesciunt, reprehenderit! Soluta voluptatibus perferendis quod nam.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/977/Mountains_Scenery_473520_2048x1152.jpg" alt="image3">
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam optio quasi sapiente labore enim nisi sit, facere adipisci corrupti distinctio. Fuga eos in debitis, recusandae rerum minus nulla sint doloribus ducimus dolore non, repellendus, ullam quia.
    Molestiae enim ratione eaque?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit nemo sit qui dolorem, minima quibusdam. Cumque aperiam sint odio culpa totam alias explicabo suscipit voluptates officiis adipisci temporibus, amet ipsum, vero voluptatibus consequatur
    rerum, aut ullam. Sequi iusto, similique. Quis eaque, veritatis sapiente ea amet, veniam neque voluptatem repellendus possimus laboriosam quasi nam aliquam ullam similique, expedita. Quo aliquam molestias ratione nemo pariatur sed velit, sint nulla
    tempore eveniet maiores nesciunt explicabo quas! Nesciunt, reprehenderit! Soluta voluptatibus perferendis quod nam.</p>
</div>
```

Чем смог.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) к сожалению, вся суть конечно в разбиении ширины на 2-колонки, сейчас попробую поменять что-нибудь с flex...

Comment: Но здесь, к вашему ответу есть тоже вопрос. Почему в этом способе по горизонтали появляется полоса прокрутки. Ее как-то можно убрать? от чего это зависит?

Comment: Вопрос хороший, попробовал несколько вариантов, единственное что выяснил, полоса идёт от браузера (Chrome, Firefox), если открыть страницу через инструменты разработчика или на мобилке (тестил в Safary), полосы нет.  Оставлю ссылку, возможно разберусь и оставлю решение там. Если решено - текст будет зелёный. https://codepen.io/-Iurii-/pen/yLvNKpd